# Problema identificando proceso " Process[] "

Tags: c#

tengo un problema leyendo e identificando un proceso, resulta que son 3 procesos diferentes pero tienen el mismo nombre, lo único que se diferencia es el PID y la Command line

yo estoy utilizando la siguiente linea de código:

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name));
 if (process.Length == 1)
            {....}
```

Se que me van a decir que use el `getprocessbyID` pero no quiero usar el PID ya que tengo entendido que este puede cambiar en los procesos.

conocen alguna forma de revisar los procesos por Command line?

quedo atento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes usar WMI para consultar los procesos. En este caso puedes consultar [Win32_Process class](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-process). Te pingo un ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_Process instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos Sergio, pero no entiendo tu código. que hace esta linea ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");

Comment: Tienes más info en la MSDN [ManagementObjectSearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Realiza una consulta de objetos de administración del sistema en un ámbito específico, en este caso en el ámbito Win32_Process cuya información está en el enlace de mi respuesta. Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) es la infraestructura para la gestión de datos y operaciones en sistemas Windows

Comment: voto negativo por que el OP pregunto como consultar los procesos por linea de comando... no por código c#

Comment: Hola. Merecido el voto negativo. Me despistó la etiqueta de la pregunta, en este caso C#. Aunque si creara una aplicación de consola como la indicada en mi respuesta, podría ejecutarla desde linea de comandos

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra Lo he solucionado con ` using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(

    "SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE name = 'firefox.exe' "))` y ya con la variable capturada la puedo escribir (Y) gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Con `TaskList` puedes ver los procesos y obtendremos la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso buscar alguno entre esta lista

```
tasklist|findstr "chrome.exe"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para detenerlos

```
TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe
```

Comment: Luciano mira tu segunda imagen, imagínate que quieras identificar **solo uno** de todos esos chrome y que lo único diferente sea el **PID** y la **linea de comandos**. por eso Tasklist no me serviría.

Comment: Hola. @thiagolope7, cual será el criterio sobre el cual diferenciar los procesos?

Comment: Una propiedad podría ser CreationDate??

Comment: Hola @SergioParraGuerra, en el TaskManager, para 3 procesos diferentes tengo igual (name,Process name), pero hacerlo por PID por el momento es una opción casi descartada ya que el valor cambia constantemente. por lo cual veo que la unica opción es Command Line, igual voy a revisar CreationDate ya que desconozco esta propiedad.

Comment: Hola. Cuando te refieres a Command Line es la ruta del ejecutable del proceso?

Comment: Si, a la ruta..

Answer (score -1):

CMD:

para procesos :

**tasklist**

para servicios :

**net start**